# How correctly use luaotfload fallback?

Tags: fonts, luatex

I would like to setup document which use by default EB Garamond font and for specific *not recognized* characters auto switch to fallback fonts. I found that it is possible by using `luaotfload` fallback. It works well on simple text like `\myfont العَرَبِ`. But I would like to use it globally on entire document and it does not work. As you can see in the example I am using `\begin{myfont}` and `\end{myfont}` to apply globally. But that is probably not right solution. I am using standard inner commands like `\begin{flushleft}` `\Large{العَرَبِ}` and that is probably the problem. Could you help me how to setup `myfont` globally?

```
\documentclass[oneside, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\directlua
{luaotfload.add_fallback
("myfallback",
{
"DejaVuSans:mode=harf;script=grek;color=FF0000;",
"cmuserif:mode=node;script=cyrl;color=00FF00;",
"NotoSansBengali:mode=harf;script=bng2;color=0000FF;",
"NotoColorEmoji:mode=harf;"
}
)
}

\font \myfont ={name:EBGaramond:mode=node;fallback=myfallback;}

\begin{document}

\begin{myfont}

Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy

\Large{Velký ביץ aaa}\small{Malý aaa טון}

العَرَبِيَّة

\Huge العَرَبِيَّة



aaaטון ביץaaa

☺️♥️✌️‍♂️‍♂️

Αν προ δετραcτο vερτερεμ, σιμιλιqθε μοδερατιθσ θτ vελ. Νθμqθαμ μινιμθμ cομπρεηενσαμ μει ει, σιτ προβο νοστρθδ οπορτερε εθ. Αγαμ ρεπριμιqθε τε ηισ, ιδ σιτ μαγνα προμπτα ινvενιρε, qθο ιν θνθμ οφφενδιτ οπορτεατ. Ιπσθμ vελιτ πρινcιπεσ αδ σεα, εξ προ διcτασ λαβιτθρ. Εθμ ετ vιρισ δελιcατισσιμι.

\end{myfont}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: size commands like `\Large` and `\small` do not take an argument.  `\Large{abc} xyz`  makes  abc and xyz (and the rest of the document) large not just abc.

Comment: Add the fallback as feature to your main font `\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[RawFeature={fallback=myfallback}]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ups, you are right, thanks :)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that is exactly what i need! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the fallback as a feature to your main font

```
 \setmainfont{EB Garamond}[RawFeature={fallback=myfallback}]
```